# Calculating Harmonic Sum

Tags: c

I wrote a program to calculate the sum of a harmonic series (1 + 1/2 + 1/3 .. + 1/n), but I'm having trouble compiling it. I went over the code a bunch of times but I don't see any syntax errors [2 are showing up when I try to compile]. Is my logic wrong, or is it syntactical?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( void ) {

 int v,p,i;
 double x=0;

 printf("Enter a value to calculate the value of this harmonic series: \n");
 scanf("%d",&v);

 if (v<=0) {
   printf("Please enter a POSITIVE number: \n");
   scanf("%d",&p);
   while (i=1; i<=v; i++) {
     x=x+(1/i);  }
     printf("The value for the series is %lf", x);
  }
    else {
      while (i=1; i<=v; i++) {
        x=x+(1/i);
      }
      printf("The value for the series is %lf", x);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you have error messages from the compiler, you should include them in the question...

Comment: Globally replacing `while` by **`for`** fixes things.

Comment: The error message didn't say much. Just that I needed a ")" before a ";" which I was sure I had right. Thanks for all the input.

Comment: I removed the `recursion` tag because your program does not use recursion and there is no reason here to start using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All those `while` should be `for`, and that `1/i` should be either `1./i` or `1/(double)i`, because otherwise an integer division is performed. Also, you should restructure your program flow to avoid that code duplication.

*But*, there's a subtle but more important mistake: due to how floating point arithmetic works, you should start to sum from smaller numbers to big ones, otherwise you may reach the point were each new addend is smaller than the current precision of that `double`, and the addition will have no effect<sup>1</sup>. So, your `for` should be reversed:

```
for (i=v; i>=1; i--)
```

---

Also: you should check the return value of the `scanf` to be 1, to make sure that the user actually inserted some valid numeric input. *And*, the `printf` specifier for `double`s is just `%f`, without the `l`.

Taking all this in account, you could rewrite the program as this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int v=0,i,ch;
    double x=0.;

    printf("Enter a value to calculate the value of this harmonic series: ");

    /* The loop calls the scanf, and is repeated as far as the user continues to
       write garbage */
    while(scanf("%d",&v)==0 || v<=0)
    {
        printf("Please enter a POSITIVE number: ");

        /* Empty the input buffer to remove the eventual garbage; the logic is
           a bit convoluted to handle the case where the user enters EOF */
        while((ch=getchar())!='\n')
            if(ch==EOF)
                return 1;
    }

    /* perform the actual sum - done from smallest to biggest term */
    for (i=v; i>=1; i--)
        x+=1./i;

    printf("The value for the series is %f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

---

1. For an harmonic series this is actually almost impossible - you would need to go to really big numbers to notice some difference - but with other series (whose terms get very small very fast) this suggestion can be really important.

Comment: Thanks for that last point. I didn't know that would make a difference as the input got bigger!

Comment: @Michele: again, for the harmonic series this is not really an issue, because you would need to go over 10^16 or something like that to notice some difference; on the other hand, if you started working with series whose terms become small faster the difference can be acknowledgeable.

Comment: "Also, you should restructure your program flow to avoid that code duplication." Actually, it's more than that: the outer while-loop in the answer code allows the users to mess up entering a positive number multiple times, repeating the question until acceptable input is provided. Please make sure you understand the logic fully.

Answer (score 5):

Bunch of errors I notice....

(1) Second scanf, you put value into p, but never use p. Hence you will test i<=v for v<=0, so the 'loop' (see later) won't run

(2) you use 'while' when you should use 'for' in your loops

(3) i is an integer, so 1/i will evaluate to 1 (for i =1 ), or 0. Make 1/((double) i) or something similar.

There might be more.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It was evaluating to 0.00000 until I read your post and changed x to equal 1.0/i

Answer (score 4):

> The error message didn't say much. Just that I needed a ")" before a ";" which I was sure I had right.

Error messages also tell you what line of the file caused the problem. You can use this information to track down the problem to the suspect `while` statements that should use `for` instead.

In your case, as others noted, you want `for (...;...;...)` instead of `while (...;...;...)`. The compiler reads your source code left to right, in a single pass*; when it gets to `while`, it expects** to see `while (...)`, so as soon as it sees `while (...;`, the `;` is flagged as an error. Note that (and I'm sure you can see why) just putting a `)` before the `;` won't solve the problem in general ;)

* It is not required to do so, but it at least used to be simpler this way, and there are things that are errors in the language specifically because it allowed compilers to do it that way. You have to remember, the C language dates to the early 1970s. Computers were a LOT less powerful back then, so programming languages often made things easier for the compiler, at the programmer's expense.

** This is, of course, a gross simplification, ignoring the details of how the `...` part is interpreted.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the error message and why the ';' was flagged. I'm not sure why emacs doesn't number it's lines as DrJava & other noob-friendly editors do. It makes it kind of hard to count all the lines and find the one that's causing problems.

Answer (score 2):

You are using for-loop syntax in your while loops:

```
while (i=1; i<=v; i++) {
```

(or vice-versa)

Try changing that to:

```
for (i=1; i<=v; i++) {
```

Also, `1/i` will always produce 0 as an answer (because they are integers), try `1.0/i`.

Lastly, why have you duplicated so many lines?  Find a way to structure your logic so that you only need those lines once.

Comment: oh, I should have caught that loop error! I was just staring at it so long, I missed it.  I guess I could do a while (true) loop so that I wouldn't need to duplicate the two loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (i=1; i<=v; i++) {
```

?

maybe you want to use a for cycle ?

```
for (i=1; i<=v; i++) {
```